# Instantiation of Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I keep getting this error when trying to instantiate a data member of a templated class:

```
Proj3Aux.h:28: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘AugmentedBinarySearchTree’ with no type
Proj3Aux.h:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

Here is the code in the class I'm trying to instantiate from:

```
class Proj3Aux
{

 private:
  AugmentedBinarySearchTree<int> m_tree;  <-- ERROR HERE
  string m_currentCmd;
  vector<int> m_inputs;
```

For some reason the call to instantiate an ABST of type `int` is throwing some sort of error.

Here is the header code for the ABST class:

```
template <class Comparable>
class AugmentedBinarySearchTree
{
 public:
  /*------------Constructors/Destructors-------------*/

  explicit AugmentedBinarySearchTree();
  AugmentedBinarySearchTree(const AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable> & rhs);
  ~AugmentedBinarySearchTree();


  /*--------------Facilitators------------------------*/

  int remove(const Comparable & x);
  bool IsPerfect();
  // bool IsComplete(); <-- Extra Credit!
  void PrintLevels(int numlevels);
  void makeEmpty();

  /*---------------Getters---------------------------*/

  int RemoveResidue(); /* Assume RemoveResidue will always be called after Prin\
t */
  const Comparable & NthElement(int n);
  int Rank(const Comparable & x);
  const Comparable & Median();
  BinaryNode<Comparable> * findMin(BinaryNode<Comparable> *t) const;


  /*---------------Setters---------------------------*/

  int insert(const Comparable & x);

 private:

  int insert(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t) const;
  int remove(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t) const;
  void PrintLevels(queue <BinaryNode<Comparable> *> q, int levels);
  void RemoveResidue(BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t, int *deletions) const;
  BinaryNode<Comparable> * NthElement(BinaryNode<Comparable> *t, int *nodesVisi\
ted, int n) const;
  void Rank(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> *t, int *nodesVisited)\
 const;
  bool IsPerfect(queue <BinaryNode<Comparable> *> q, int height);
  void makeEmpty(BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t) const;
  //IsComplete  <-- Extra Credit!

  /*------------------Members-----------------------------*/
  BinarySearchTree<Comparable> m_tree;
  BinaryNode<Comparable> *root;
};

#include "AugmentedBinarySearchTree.cpp"
```

The definition of the `BinaryNode` class is above this given code, and within the ABST cpp file all methods are defined in the correct manner:

```
template <class Comparable>
<return type> AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable>::<method>(<parameters>)
```

Any help please?

EDIT:

Beginning of `Proj3Aux.h`:

```
#ifndef PROJ3_AUX_H_
#define PROJ3_AUX_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "AugmentedBinarySearchTree.h"
using namespace std;

const char COMMENT = '#';

class Proj3Aux
{

 private:
  //AugmentedBinarySearchTree<int> m_tree;
  string m_currentCmd;
  vector<int> m_inputs;

 public:
  /*
   * Enum to contain all commands available
   */
  enum COMMANDS {PRINT, RESIDUALS, RANK, NTH, MEDIAN, REMOVE, PERFECT,
                 COMPLETE};

  /*
   * Proj3Aux
   * Default class constructor
   * Preconditoins: none
   * Postconditions: new instance of Proj3Aux is created
   */
  Proj3Aux();
```

Comment: Looks like a name lookup problem. Are you sure the template `classAugmentedBinarySearchTree` is declared *before* `Proj3Aux`?

Comment: In `Proj3Aux.h`, did you include the header that declares `AugmentedBinarySearchTree`?

Comment: @DanielStrul Yes, they are in separate files and @crayzeewulf `AugmentedBinarySearchTree.h` is included in the file

Comment: They may be in separate files, but included in the wrong order. In particular, why is there a code line that says `#include "AugmentedBinarySearchTree.cpp"` at the end of your header file??

Comment: @DanielStrul I never understood that either but the ABST code is given from instructors that we aren't supposed to edit.

Comment: @m_callens OK, thanks for this clarification. What we can ascertain here is that the compiler doesn't know that `AugmentedBinarySearchTree` is a template name (it complains when parsing the angular braket). Could you include in your question the full header for `Proj3Aux.h` (not necessarily full, but at least the 30 first lignes or so)?

Comment: @DanielStrul the edit was main to the question. I commented the error line to continue testing other features temporarily

Comment: @m_callens Thanks... It looks OK... Last possibility I see is if `AugmentedBinarySearchTree` is in another namespace. If not, I'm out of ideas :-(

Comment: @DanielStrul haha its ok, thank you anyway! I'm extremely confused as to why there's an error.